# Apache webgate integration with docker application

Tags: apache, docker, containers, single-sign-on, oam

My application is working in a `docker container` in port `80`. I'm planning to integrate `SSO` with this application, we are using `OAM apache webgate` to integrate `SSO`. I need help in structuring this integration.

I previously integrated `apache webgate` with my `docker container` directly and got into a state like, i cannot rebuild my image anymore.

Can i integrate `apache webgate` on my host and still integrate SSO with application inside docker?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. OAM WebGate is just like any other apache plugin/module and can work inside the docker container.